# Pass @input property value from an angular component into component module

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular2-observables, ngrx-store

I am currently working on an Angular component where I would like to have a dynamic store name, for my ngrx/store(feature module). As a result, I have added an `@Input() storeName: string;` value to my component. I want to be able to specify the storeName on the html DOM and pass it to the store. That, however, is my precise issue. I am not sure as how to pass an @Input() value from my component to my module.

The idea is:

```
StoreModule.forFeature('myStoreName', myReducer, {initialState: myInputInitialState}).
```

so that instead of myStoreName, it can be the `@Input` value created on the component. Any suggestions are more than welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Actually you want to pass data from parent component to child component?

Comment: the answer is you can't. That's not how modules work.

Comment: The input value, as well as store is on parent component. However, that is a possible work around. Potentially creating the store on the child component, and having the value be passed from parent to child.

Comment: @bryan60 I would like to explore the option potentially using observables. The featureName for StoreModule.forFeature does indeed allow for the use of a function. It's simply that the value needs to be available on storeCreation.

Comment: It allows a function, but you can't pass an input to a module. Observables are just a method of asynchronous event handling. They're not a mysterious magic bullet.

Comment: @bryan60 even with the potential use of a subscribe function?

Comment: Already answered. good luck with this.

Comment: As a store's purpose is state management and is built on Observables, is there any reason both the parent and the child cannot access the store's data? That would be the correct use of the store and common practice.

Comment: @joh04667 you are correct, and that is already implemented regarding the store data. The question here, is can I create the storeName dynamically, not the content inside the store object. For instance, I would like to instantiate the component one place, and call the store person: 
```
person: {
  firstName: 'Jake',
  lastName: 'Larry'
}
```

and then in another place, instantiate the component, and call it the store cat:
```
cat: {
  firstName: 'Jake',
  lastName: 'Larry'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All things considered, I realized what I was doing was an anti-pattern. Even if I would have the option to instantiate a module, with an input value passed through a component(which for reasons of AOT I cannot), those values would ultimately have to be passed elsewhere.

Instead, I did indeed give this component a state feature name that is static. However, this state get's passed elsewhere, when a particular event handler is called. Staying true to what this input component is supposed to be, a temporary state, until user is able to submit, or any other event for that matter. I believe this to be similar for all other situations with dynamic components.